# Spring Boot - Token authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have access to a web application which has a link to another application I'm developing. When that link is clicked the URL is filled with two parameters: **user**, and **token**.

This token is generated per every user login on that very same web application.
I want to use that token and user to authenticate someone in the application I'm developing!

I have access to the source app's database in order to query against the token and username.

However I need help finding a way to implement this logic with Spring-Boot. Do I need a custom filter / authentication provider? How to wire these things up with Spring?

I want to stick to the framework rather than developing my own solution for this.

**TL;DR: I need help securing a RESTful controller with a token I obtain through GET**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write filter to authenticate token.

If you want make architecture a bit better I would recommend creating gateway (i.e. Zuul) and invoke second application through gateway. Implement gateway to authenticate requests. In my architecture I create separate Auth component to generate token and validate token. Gateway could call Auth to validate token.

Comment: Hey! Suppose I don't have access to the first application though (I shouldn't touch it), and let's assume it must generate the token...
From what I know the filter only decides which users can see what, right?
I still need a custom authentication provider?